# How can I inject Azure DevOps pipeline run number in a build artifact file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I would like to have the Azure Devops pipeline build identifier (in red below) displayed in my deployed Angular app. Any suggestion on how can I do it, please?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the File Transformation task? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform?view=azure-devops. If the file you're planning to modify is XML or JSON configuration file, it might be the easiest option.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko - yes, I am aware of it. But my problem is that I don't know how to reference the actual build number - "202120922.7" in my screenshot above in a task like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` variable to get this value. And now it depends what you have already in your angular application.

For instance you can set this value in `environment.ts` file

```
// environment.ts environment variables
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  APIEndpoint: 'https://dev.endpoint.com'
  buildNumber: '#{Build.BuildNumber}#`
};
```

Via [Token replace extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens)

```
- task: qetza.replacetokens.replacetokens-task.replacetokens@3
  displayName: 'Replace tokens'
  inputs:
    targetFiles: |
      **/environment.ts
```

You need to run this step before you compile angular app so the value reach your config.